# install sql server on ubuntu agent in azure pipelines

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu, azure-pipelines

Using azure ubuntu latest agent. how can I install sql server on ubuntu-latest agent in azure pipelines? tried the following but causing errors

```
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      sudo apt-get update
      sudo apt-get install mssql-server
```

Comment: Did you register the SQL Server repository after updating your GPG keys? Posting what error you are getting may help in diagnosing. On a vanilla Ubuntu 20.04 LTS installation I get "E: Unable to locate package mssql-server" but steps posted here worked for me: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to Import the public repository GPG keys and register the SQL Server Ubuntu repository.

```
wget -qO- https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo apt-key add –
sudo add-apt-repository "$(wget -qO- https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/mssql-server-preview.list)
```

"

Please refer to the document: [Quickstart: Install SQL Server and create a database on Ubuntu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu?view=sql-server-ver16)